# ImportError: cannot import name WebAPI

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I wanna use "shodan" API but It didn't work well with me.

First I did this command in terminal `easy_install shodan` 
and here's the ouptut:

```
$easy_install shodan
Searching for shodan
Best match: shodan 0.8.1
Processing shodan-0.8.1-py2.7.egg
shodan 0.8.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shodan-0.8.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for shodan
Finished processing dependencies for shodan
```

and then I wrote my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python en

    from shodan import WebAPI

    SHODAN_API_KEY = "Key"

    api = WebAPI(SHODAN_API_KEY)


    # Wrap the request in a try/ except block to catch errors
```

It gave me an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name WebAPI
```

I searched for similar problems some answers was changing file name and some was deleting pyc files. I tried both answers but It doesn't work also.

Comment: It seems that the indentation of your code is not correct but I think you should have a IndentationError rather than a ImportError if it was the cause of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 
I should install py crypto

sudo apt-get install python-crypto

Answer (score 3):

What's the name of your script? There could be a name collision going on if the name of your script is "shodan", i.e. the same name as the Shodan library. There was also an issue with Python 3 that caused some import problems, but if you're using the latest version of the Shodan API library that should be resolved. And I echo the comment of luc that the indentation looks wrong, so you will need to fix that as well in order for the script to execute.

Comment: I had this exact same problem and your answer was correct for me - I stupidly named my script 'shodan', which of course caused name collision.